# I am having an issue with a simple triangle calculation program in java

Tags: java, math

**Main method:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangeRunner
{
    // private instance variables
    private static double a, b, c;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Instantiated an object from the class calcArea
        calcArea test = new calcArea();
        // Instantiated a Scanner object for user input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter side A ::");
        a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter side B ::");
        b = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter side C ::");
        c = keyboard.nextDouble();
        // Taking the referenced object test and calling 3 classes within 
        // within calcArea. (calcArea, setNums, toString)
        test.calcArea(a, b, c);
        test.setNums(a, b, c);
        test.toString();
    }
}
```

**External Class:**

```
public class calcArea
{
    private double sa, sb, sc, s, area, perimeter;
    public void setNums(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        this.sa = a;
        this.sb = b;
        this.sc = c;
    }

    public void calcArea(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        perimeter = a + b + c;
        s = perimeter / 2;
        area = Math.sqrt((s * (s-sa) * (s-sb) * (s-sc)));
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("The sides" + sa + ", " + sb + ", " + sc + " create the perimeter which is then divided by two which yields " + s + " which is then fed into herons formula: Math.sqrt(side * (side-sidea) * (side-sideb) * (side-sidec)) which produces an area of" + area);
    }
}
```

My focus on this program was to

1. create a simple program for calculating the area of a triangle and
2. for practice.

There are no errors, so I think my mistake is some where in my `toString` method or in the `setNums` method.

When I run the program, it prompts me for the sides and after that there is nothing. I am doing this in BlueJ as I am using Intellij for my class work and there are complications for adding classes to it.

Please tell me if you need any further clarification.

Comment: You don't seem to understand how a constructor works. You are supposed to write `calcArea test = new calcArea(a,b,c);`.

Comment: You have to print the string. Strings and numbers don't get automatically printed to the screen, otherwise your programm would be outputting a whole lot of nonsense that would clock up the screen.

Comment: You are not printing it and you are expecting it to show up on your console. try : `System.out.println(test.toString());` Also, look at some example of OOP.

Comment: @Gendarme that's because `calcArea(double, double, double)` is not meant to be a constructor but since the class name does not follow Java standard naming it looks like one.

Comment: @D.B. You're right. I read it too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) because you have a class name that starts with lowercase and that's not the accepted practice. It's confusing for others to read, especially because you have this method `public void calcArea(double a, double b, double c)` which looks like a constructor but isn't.

Also, you seem to be mixing different implementation strategies here because you have this:

```
    test.calcArea(a, b, c);
    test.setNums(a, b, c);
```

which calculates area before setting the variables via `setNums` and at the same time inside your `calcArea` class you don't take advantage of these variables: `private double sa, sb, sc` when you calculate the area but instead ask for them as parameters of the method `calcArea`.

Here is an example of some of the improvements I would make to your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stuff
{
    // private instance variables
    private static double a, b, c;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Instantiated an object from the class calcArea
        CalcArea test = new CalcArea();
        // Instantiated a Scanner object for user input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter side A ::");
        a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter side B ::");
        b = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter side C ::");
        c = keyboard.nextDouble();
        // Taking the referenced object test and calling 3 classes within 
        // within calcArea. (calcArea, setNums, toString)
        test.setNums(a, b, c);
        test.calcArea();
        System.out.println(test.toString());
        keyboard.close(); //don't forget to close resources.
    }
}


public class CalcArea
{
    private double sideA, sideB, sideC, s, area, perimeter;
    public void setNums(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {
        this.sideA = sideA;
        this.sideB = sideB;
        this.sideC = sideC;
    }

    public void calcArea()
    {
        perimeter = sideA + sideB + sideC;
        s = perimeter / 2;
        area = Math.sqrt((s * (s-sideA) * (s-sideB) * (s-sideC)));
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("The sides" + sideA + ", " + sideB + ", " + sideC + " create the perimeter which is then divided by two which yields " + s + " which is then fed into herons formula: Math.sqrt(side * (side-sidea) * (side-sideb) * (side-sidec)) which produces an area of " + area);
    }
}
```

Notice how I set the class member variables first, then calculate the area, then print results:

```
        test.setNums(a, b, c);
        test.calcArea();
        System.out.println(test.toString());
```

Also notice how the class name `CalcArea` now begins with a capital and it's less confusing when reading the method `public void calcArea()`.

See how `public void calcArea()` does not take any parameters but instead uses the values that were set by the `setNums` methods earlier.

Comment: I understand the class naming conventions, I also see my error in my use of test.setNums() and with test.calcArea() I was messing around with them and decided to leave it in. I figured that my toString methods return would print fine, but now that I see it printing the toString method is better.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by, "I figured that my toString methods return would print fine" because there is a huge difference between a `return` and invoking the `println` method on a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out). Simply returning a value does **NOT** cause it to be printed.

Comment: I understand that, my understanding came from knowing that System.out.print would return the return from a method, essentially.